# Database on a shared network drive, only clientside?

Tags: php, jquery, xml, ajax, database

this my first Post and I really couldn't find a solution for my problem.

I'm working on an internal teamsite for my office, all the files are on a network drive.
Now I want to write a Newssystem, I already managed to read my xml file with jquery ajax, but found out that I can't write to the xml file without having php/server.

So here's what I've done so far to show all the news in a table

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
       type: "GET",
       url: "db/news.xml",
       dataType: "xml",
       success: function(xml) {
        $(xml).find('news').each(function(){
            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            var title = $(this).find('title').text();
            var author = $(this).find('author').text();
            var date = $(this).find('date').text();
            var content = $(this).find('content').text();
            $('#tabs-1').append("<table class='news' width='1000px'><tr><td width='950px' class='newstitle'>"+title+"</td><td class='newsdate'>"+date+"</td></tr><tr><td colspan='2' class='newscontent'>"+content+"</td></tr></table>");
        });
    }});
});
```

Is there any way I can read and write to a "database" (xml, sqlite, w.e), having everything on that shared network drive? If that's not possible, what would be the easiest solution when I could use a webserver with php and mysql, only having the php file that will write to the db on the webserver?

Hope you understand what I want to do.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

there are many solutions.. since you mention php installing web server to your network and using SQLite stored into net drive will do the trick.
php script will be intepreted by the server and stored there..

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer, but I can't install php somewhere internal, I could only use an external webserver. I now looked for a solution with JSONP, since I have to keep all files on the network drive and only having a php file external. But then I had to find out that with JSONP you can't do POST requests. Well after looking around for hours I guess there is no solution, nothing serverside = no db.

Comment: in that case only custom build standalone applications would offer everything you are looking.. also the web server has to offer somekind of service for you to interact with such as REST allowing acess to db transactions

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible with JavaScript alone. You will need some server-side interaction somewhere. This is because the way browsers are built is to the standards, policies, and security practices of whatever organization that governs that stuff.

But overall JavaScript is a Client-Side language. It has no access or rights over a file system, and browsers are developed to keep it that way as it would be an insanely high security risk otherwise, as anyone can add "inject" javascript into any site thats open in there window at any time.

Bottom line is you will need some level of server side interaction, be it php, or otherwise.